# Boundary Conditions for Continuum Mechanics

Tags: boundary-conditions

If I'm given some sort of shape and there is a displacement given but there are no external forces acting on the body, do I still need to write down the traction free boundary conditions or will there only be displacement boundary conditions?

Comment: I suggest that you check [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26495/well-posedness-of-elasticity-boundary-conditions/26497#26497) first. After that, yes you can have a problem with only displacement boundary conditions. This is not usual, though.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm gonna make a separate question with a picture included so I can show you what I mean